# Is there a Listener for when an actor gets resized?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, resize, actor

I was wondering if there is an easier way to execute a specific method on a resize than what I have written in the code snippet below.

```
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
        for (Table t : tabPane.tabs) {
            resize(stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth(), t);
        }
    }


private void resize(float width, Group group) {
        SnapshotArray<Actor> children = group.getChildren();
        Actor[] arr = children.begin();
        for (Actor a : arr) {
            if (a instanceof SoundButton) {
                ((SoundButton) a).resized(width);
            } else if (a instanceof Group) {
                resize(width, (Group) a);
            }
        }
        children.end();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Override sizeChanged()

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks that works better. Maybe post it as an answer so I cqn mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Actor class has a method which you can override called [sizeChanged](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#sizeChanged--)

```
@Override
public void sizeChanged() {
   // Add Your code here
}
```